# Somar fatores de um data frame?

Tags: r

Tenho o seguinte df:

```
Factor  Valor
  F1     1.224
  F1     1.533
  F1     0,77429
  F2     3.477
  F2     2.6767
  F3     0.557
  F3     1
```

Como faço para ter o total dos valores?

Answer (score 2):

Para ter a soma de uma variável com relação aos valore de outra variável fator em um data frame, tem maneiras. A minha preferida é usando o pacote `dplyr`:

Primeiro construo o seguinte data frame com variáveis fator:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(32)
df <- data.frame(
                letras = as.factor(sample(size = 10000, replace = TRUE ,x = letters)),
                valor = rnorm(10000))
```

Assim, agrupando os dados com a função `dplyr::group_by` posso sumariar sumariar os dados com `summarise`:

```
> df %>% 
    +   dplyr::group_by(letras) %>% 
    +   dplyr::summarise(soma_valor = sum(valor))
# A tibble: 26 x 2
    letras soma_valor
    <fctr>      <dbl>
1      a -13.947423
2      b -37.894710
3      c  -4.600648
4      d  50.555644
5      e  30.048488
6      f  -3.667602
7      g -19.215489
8      h   2.892579
9      i  31.189657
10     j  17.085478
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Para saber mais sobre o dplyr e todo o tidyverse, leia esse link [aqui](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Luiz, para um Data Frame você pode usar o `ColSums()` para pegar os valores nas tabelas.

`colSums(coluna[,-1])`

ou
`sum(dataFrame$Coluna)`

e removendo os valores NA
`sum(dataFrame$Coluna,na.rm=TRUE)`

o `[-1]` garante que o nome da coluna nãos será contado.

Ou para um approach mais genérico você pode usar o

`colSums(Filter(is.numeric, dataFrame$Coluna))`

Note que você pode ter ajuda no console digitando `?sum` ou `?colSums`

[Fonte](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html)